# How can I setup Minecraft Mixins?

Tags: java, client, minecraft, mixins

I am trying to make kind of a Minecraft Client, just enough features to say it is, using Mixins, but I can't seem to setup the workspace. I have looked everywhere yet I can't find a clear answer. I have 1 year experience in Java making SpigotMC plugins and I messed around in MCP when I was bored and made things but you can't publish it so it didnt go anywhere. Can someone please help me because I have been looking everywhere on the internet and I couldn't find an answer.

I have tried following the readme.md on the Sponge Mixins GitHub but it wasn't as clear of an answer but it didn't work and also I don't think that is the right place to find how to set it up.

Comment: Very unclear. What is your workspace, MCP, Forge, Fabric, Paper, Sponge? What have you already tried, what are the errors (if any).

Comment: My workspace is Sponge and my problem is that I don't know how to set it up in Eclipse so that is what I need help with.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what version of Minecraft you are looking for, you will have to use Gradle anyway. It's kind of very complicated. For 1.14.4 I would use fabric(its a mod loader like a forge, it doesn't use MCP mappings tho, due to copyright, hopefully soon it will use Mojang 1.15 mappings), https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:setup. This is VERY easy to set up, just download the example mod from their Github, and run the `gradlew` command. For 1.12.2-1.14.4 like a client version, I would suggest looking at baritones Github, https://github.com/cabaletta/baritone, you will have to know a bit about Gradle to remove their custom stuff, etc. For a "plain" 1.12.2 forge setup I would suggest looking at https://github.com/zeroeightysix/KAMI, Mixins aren't available for forge 1.13.2+ as of right now so you cant use forge for those versions. I know this is a bit late but maybe for someone in the future, or even you. Personally I only use fabric(out of the 3 examples I sent), I set them up differently my self, but you definitely will now be able to setup mixins.